# A convergent / divergent sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to find both a convergent and divergent sequence of positive numbers such that $$\lim \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=1$$

I think the question is asking me to play with the ratio test.

Just when I was about to write down the answer, I realize that my answer was for series. (The ratio test is for series, right?)

Could you help me with sequence?

Comment: $s_n = n^{\pm 1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convergent sequence: $s_n = \dfrac 1n$.

Divergent sequence $s_n = n$.

Comment: You can also play with the ratio tests for the general term of a series: Convergent series general term $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n^2}$, divergent series general term $a_n = n$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU to go with the green! +1

Answer (score 1):

You've been answered, but if you want to tighten up the conditions and that both sequences are convergent to zero but with one we have a convergent series and the other one a divergent one, then take

$$\begin{align*}a_n&=\frac1n\;\;\;\text{divergent series}\\
a_n&=\frac1{n^2}\;\;\;\text{convergent series}\end{align*}$$

Comment: +NiceDon+${}{}{}{}$